# Angular 3 forms 2 either condition disable button

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-forms

In my angular project I've 3 forms

which is of structure

```
 --form1
   --form2
   --form3
```

Inside my form 1 there is form 2 and 3. I want to disable the button if form 1 is invalid and one of the other 2 forms are invalid, disable the button. If form 1 is valid either of form2 or form3 is valid the button should gets enabled.

I tried with this condition

```
<button [disabled]="!form1.valid || (!form2.valid || !form3.valid)" />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try
`<button [disabled]="!form1.valid && (!form2.valid || !form3.valid)" />`

Comment: Not Working! I tried this combination already, the first condition is the form1 should be invalid and the second condition be (either of the forms 2 or 3 should be invalid) to disable the button. But if either of the forms 2 or 3 is valid then the buttons should be in enable condition

Comment: If form 2 or form 3 is valid and form 1 is invalid then what will happen?

Comment: the button gets enabled!

Comment: Thanks for your response buddy, I got the solution. It is `[disabled]="!form1.valid || (!form2.valid && !form3.valid)"` it disables the button when form 1 is invalid and (form 2 or form3 is invalid) and enables when the form 1 is valid and either of the form 2 or 3 is valid.